# VSFTPD Wont Start on Rackspace Host

Tags: vsftpd

I have a server on Rackspace that I wish to enable FTP on. However, I cannot get the service to start. Using the exact same setup on a local virtualbox, (same distro, kernel, vsftpd installation steps, and same configuration file /etc/vsftpd.conf), it works perfectly.

The config file at /etc/vsftpd.conf is as follows:

```
listen=YES
anonymous_enable=NO
local_enable=YES
write_enable=YES
dirmessage_enable=YES
use_localtime=YES
xferlog_enable=YES
connect_from_port_20=YES
#chroot_local_user=YES
secure_chroot_dir=/var/run/vsftpd/empty
pam_service_name=vsftpd
rsa_cert_file=/etc/ssl/private/vsftpd.pem
```

It also appears that nothing gets added to the log file at `/var/log/vsftpd.log`

I believe the service never starts correctly because I can never see the port 21 open when using nmap, and whenever I perform sudo service vsftpd restart, I get `stop: Unknown instance:` instead of `vsftpd stop/waiting`. However I never see any kind of error message.

I checked the /var/run/vsftpd/empty directory exists as well as the rsa cert file.

I also tried temporarily disabling the ufw firewall (although it already allows port 21).

Are there any other permissions/configurations I need to check?

uname -a output: `3.8.0-38-generic #56~precise1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Mar 13 16:22:48 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

---

Update

The output of /var/log/syslog is as follows:

```
3 12:35:15 annonymous kernel: [18271.505345] BUG: Bad page map in process vsftpd  pte:8000000000000165 pmd:1b03f067
Apr  3 12:35:15 annonymous kernel: [18271.505358] page:ffffea0000000000 count:-174 mapcount:-174 mapping:          (null) index:0x0
Apr  3 12:35:15 annonymous kernel: [18271.505367] page flags: 0x14(referenced|dirty)
Apr  3 12:35:15 annonymous kernel: [18271.505377] addr:00007f315f3bc000 vm_flags:00100071 anon_vma:ffff88001b0af180 mapping:          (null) index:7f315f3bc
Apr  3 12:35:15 annonymous kernel: [18271.505389] Pid: 26581, comm: vsftpd Tainted: G    B        3.8.0-38-generic #56~precise1-Ubuntu
Apr  3 12:35:15 annonymous kernel: [18271.505391] Call Trace:
Apr  3 12:35:15 annonymous kernel: [18271.505399]  [<ffffffff8115c3a9>] print_bad_pte+0x1d9/0x270
Apr  3 12:35:15 annonymous kernel: [18271.505403]  [<ffffffff8115e53e>] zap_pte_range+0x3de/0x440
Apr  3 12:35:15 annonymous kernel: [18271.505408]  [<ffffffff81005dc0>] ? xen_make_pte+0x20/0x70
Apr  3 12:35:15 annonymous kernel: [18271.505412]  [<ffffffff8100544d>] ? __raw_callee_save_xen_make_pte+0x11/0x1e
Apr  3 12:35:15 annonymous kernel: [18271.505415]  [<ffffffff81005489>] ? __raw_callee_save_xen_pmd_val+0x11/0x1e
Apr  3 12:35:15 annonymous kernel: [18271.505419]  [<ffffffff8115e766>] unmap_page_range+0x1c6/0x320
Apr  3 12:35:15 annonymous kernel: [18271.505424]  [<ffffffff81142369>] ? __pagevec_lru_add_fn+0xb9/0xf0
Apr  3 12:35:15 annonymous kernel: [18271.505428]  [<ffffffff8115e947>] unmap_single_vma+0x87/0x100
Apr  3 12:35:15 annonymous kernel: [18271.505432]  [<ffffffff8115f204>] unmap_vmas+0x54/0xa0
Apr  3 12:35:15 annonymous kernel: [18271.505435]  [<ffffffff8116756c>] exit_mmap+0x9c/0x170
Apr  3 12:35:15 annonymous kernel: [18271.505440]  [<ffffffff8105788a>] mmput.part.22+0x4a/0x120
Apr  3 12:35:15 annonymous kernel: [18271.505444]  [<ffffffff81057989>] mmput+0x29/0x30
Apr  3 12:35:15 annonymous kernel: [18271.505447]  [<ffffffff8105fd3a>] exit_mm+0x10a/0x130
Apr  3 12:35:15 annonymous kernel: [18271.505451]  [<ffffffff810fbd55>] ? taskstats_exit+0x45/0x270
Apr  3 12:35:15 annonymous kernel: [18271.505455]  [<ffffffff816f66f5>] ? _raw_spin_lock_irq+0x15/0x20
Apr  3 12:35:15 annonymous kernel: [18271.505459]  [<ffffffff8105fec3>] do_exit+0x163/0x480
Apr  3 12:35:15 annonymous kernel: [18271.505463]  [<ffffffff8119c9e0>] ? vfs_write+0x110/0x180
Apr  3 12:35:15 annonymous kernel: [18271.505467]  [<ffffffff81060274>] do_group_exit+0x44/0xa0
Apr  3 12:35:15 annonymous kernel: [18271.505471]  [<ffffffff810602e7>] sys_exit_group+0x17/0x20
Apr  3 12:35:15 annonymous kernel: [18271.505475]  [<ffffffff816ff25d>] system_call_fastpath+0x1a/0x1f
Apr  3 12:35:15 annonymous kernel: [18271.505560] BUG: Bad rss-counter state mm:ffff880004b48b40 idx:0 val:-1
Apr  3 12:35:15 annonymous kernel: [18271.585722] BUG: Bad rss-counter state mm:ffff880004b48b40 idx:1 val:1
Apr  3 12:35:15 annonymous kernel: [18271.597942] BUG: Bad page map in process vsftpd  pte:8000000000000165 pmd:02463067
Apr  3 12:35:15 annonymous kernel: [18271.597962] page:ffffea0000000000 count:-175 mapcount:-175 mapping:          (null) index:0x0
Apr  3 12:35:15 annonymous kernel: [18271.597973] page flags: 0x14(referenced|dirty)
Apr  3 12:35:15 annonymous kernel: [18271.597985] addr:00007fe0c9a67000 vm_flags:00100071 anon_vma:ffff88001b0af500 mapping:          (null) index:7fe0c9a67
Apr  3 12:35:15 annonymous kernel: [18271.597999] Pid: 26584, comm: vsftpd Tainted: G    B        3.8.0-38-generic #56~precise1-Ubuntu
```

I am guessing that a bad page map error is the result of the fact that I am using a large amount of the memory and gone into swap?

Comment: is there anything in syslog (`grep 'vsftp' /var/log/syslog`)?

Comment: @steeldriver updated question with the log, looks useful

Comment: There seem to be a few web hits for that particular error `Bad page map in process vsftpd` --> https://lkml.org/lkml/2014/1/21/544 for example - hope this helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I gave up on vsftpd and went with proftpd which eventually worked.
For some reason proftp would not start in inetd mode and I had to change the config file to be standalone.

[Here is the tutorial I used](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-set-up-proftpd-on-ubuntu-12-04#tutorial-comment-submit) to install proftp and the "bugfix" described was in the comments